# Change boot perminantly to Single user mode with gui

Tags: boot, single-user

I am making a computer testing image for my work. I also want this to run automagically at startup, or at least simply without having to input passwords and start things manually etc. We have a lot of machines we test...

- I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64
- I am using the BurnInTest Linux version as the testing software.
- At the end I want need to run DD to write a small dos .img file with BIOS updates to the hard drive.
- I want to run badblocks to test the hard drive.
- I may need other things to run as root in the future but I could probably figure those out once I figure these out.

I figured booting into single user mode with a GUI would make this easier. 
I have tried to start a program as root but couldn't figure it out. I also tried changing the grub entry with e and then changing it to single mode but it wouldn't start the gui. When I typed "startx" it showed up a bit but didn't work fully.

I also tried using the OS the Passmark recommends (Slax) I use but it does not boot on the newer machines.

I also know that this is a **huge security risk**. I understand that. These machines are **airgapped on their own network and  locked in a room that requires badge access.**,  .

I'm not committed to Ubuntu 14.04 if another version is easier to do this with, I just need a version that will work with my newer machines. (Dell E7250s, Dell E7450s, Lenovo T450s, Lenovo T550s, etc)

Thanks for the input.